# Select records within the time range

Tags: mariadb

I would like a help ... the clinic has several doctors and each one has a specific time of care. Example: 07:00 to 12:00, 12:00 to 17:00, 09:00 to 15:00 ... What is the SQL statement to display only records within the specified time range in the start_time and end_time ?

fields:

```
start_time | end_time
07:00:00   | 12:30:00
09:00:00   | 15:00:00
12:30:00   | 17:00:00
07:00:00   | 17:00:00
```

That is, in the morning, display only the records that are part of 07:00:00 to 12:30:00 from the current time. If it's afternoon show only record that are part of 12:30:00 until 17:00:00.

Thankful.

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: I would like it to return only as follows ... let's say the current time is 9:32 and when requesting registration at this time, you should only return the records that are within the hours of 07:00:00 to 12:30: 00 from the current time ...

If by chance there is record that should release from 10:00:00, for example, it should not display because the current time is still 9:32.

Comment: And the row: 09:00:00 to 15:00:00, should be returned?

Comment: There was a typo ... sorry ... it's actually 8:32.

Comment: Ok, the time is: 8.32. Which rows should be returned from your sample data?

Comment: As the current time is 08:32, you should only return the lines that run from 07:00:00 to 12:30:00. It still has a status field set to true, by default ...

Is there a way to make mysql itself set the true value to the missing field from the specified time in start_time?

Comment: Edit your question and mention all that you said in the comments by providing examples so to clarify what you want.